# How to do 2 queries in the same sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB in which I save all the daily visits to a lot of websites, the fields of the day table are name, nvisit and date

I want to make a comparison between the visits of the day before yesterday and those of yesterday, so the result to show should be 3 rows. name, the day before yesterday and yesterday

I have tried with this query but it shows me everything in 2 rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT name as nombre, nvisit as anteayer
    from day
    WHERE date < CURDATE() -1 and date > CURDATE() -2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name as nombre, nvisit as ayer
    from day
    where date < CURDATE() and date > CURDATE() -1
    GROUP by name
    )
    day
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

When executing the sentence the result is:

```
|name         |beforeyesterday|
|.............|...............|
|example1.com |2154           |
|example1.com |3215           |
|example2.com |1524           |
|example2.com |2546           |
```

What I need:

```
|name         |beforeyesterday|yesterday|
|.............|...............|.........|
|example1.com |2154           |3215     |
|example2.com |1524           |2546     |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would want a separate row for each `name` with the columns for the counts on the various days:

```
select name,
       sum(case when date < curdate() and date > curdate - interval 1 day
                then nvisit
           end) as yesterday,
       sum(case when date < curdate() - interval 1 day and date > curdate - interval 2 day
                then nvisit
           end) as day_before
from day
group by name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me in the end with this code:
```
select name, 
  sum(case when date < CURDATE() -1 and date > CURDATE() -2
         then nvisit 
        end) as yesterday,
        sum(case when date < CURDATE() and date > CURDATE() -1 
            then nvisit 
        end) as day_before 
from day 
group by name 
```

Comment: @yuso88 . . . I would advise you to use interval arithmetic.  You can see the difference here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28d7e3ca3865ab99f7611306bfcfc34f.